# Add Read More Button to Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm in need on making some changes on Point Finder Wordpress Theme.

I Need to add a read more button to the custom postype posts for "Properties" that are displayed on the Listings page, just like it would show on most blog posts. First the excerpt and then a read more link or button below it.

I see that under the theme files there is the archive.php where the code for the listings archive is. But i'm not sure what to look at here to find a way to make this modification.

Here is the code for that File:

```
<?php 

get_header();



    global $wp_query;

    $pf_category = 0;

    $pf_mapheader_arr = array('pointfinderltypes'=>'','pointfinderitypes'=>'','pointfinderlocations'=>'','pointfinderfeatures'=>'','pointfinderconditions'=>'',);

    $get_termname = $get_term_nameforlink = '';

    if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'])){

        $taxonomy_name = $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'];

        if (in_array($taxonomy_name, array('pointfinderltypes','pointfinderitypes','pointfinderconditions','pointfinderlocations','pointfinderfeatures'))) {



            $term_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['term'];

            $pf_category = 1;

            $term_name = get_term_by('slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy_name,'ARRAY_A');



            $get_termname = $term_name['name'];

            $get_term_nameforlink = '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term_name['term_id'], $taxonomy_name ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s","pointfindert2d" ), $term_name['name']) ) . '">'.$term_name['name'].'</a>';



            if (!empty($term_name['parent'])) {

                $term_parent_name = get_term_by('id', $term_name['parent'], $taxonomy_name,'ARRAY_A');

                $get_termname = $term_parent_name['name'].' / '.$term_name['name'];

                $get_term_nameforlink = '<a href="'.get_term_link( $term_name['parent'], $taxonomy_name ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s","pointfindert2d" ), $term_parent_name['name']) ) . '">'.$term_parent_name['name'].'</a> / '.'<a href="'.get_term_link( $term_name['term_id'], $taxonomy_name ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s","pointfindert2d" ), $term_name['name']) ) . '">'.$term_name['name'].'</a>';

            }



            $filter_text = '';



            switch ($taxonomy_name) {

                case 'pointfinderltypes':

                    $filter_text .= 'listingtype = "'.$term_name['term_id'].'"';

                    $pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderltypes'] = $term_name['term_id'];

                    break;



                case 'pointfinderitypes':

                    $filter_text .= 'itemtype = "'.$term_name['term_id'].'"';

                    $pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderitypes'] = $term_name['term_id'];

                    break;



                case 'pointfinderlocations':

                    $filter_text .= 'locationtype = "'.$term_name['term_id'].'"';

                    $pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderlocations'] = $term_name['term_id'];

                    break;



                case 'pointfinderfeatures':

                    $filter_text .= 'features = "'.$term_name['term_id'].'"';

                    $pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderfeatures'] = $term_name['term_id'];

                    break;



                case 'pointfinderconditions':

                    $filter_text .= 'conditions = "'.$term_name['term_id'].'"';

                    $pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderconditions'] = $term_name['term_id'];

                    break;

            }



        }

    }







    $setup3_pointposttype_pt1 = PFSAIssetControl('setup3_pointposttype_pt1','','pfitemfinder');

    $setup22_searchresults_defaultppptype = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_defaultppptype','','10');

    $setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype','','ASC');

    $setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype','','ID');



    if ($pf_category == 0) {

        $setup_item_blogcatpage_sidebarpos = PFASSIssetControl('setup_item_blogcatpage_sidebarpos','','2');

        if(function_exists('PFGetDefaultPageHeader')){PFGetDefaultPageHeader();}

        echo '<div class="pf-blogpage-spacing pfb-top"></div>';

        echo '<section role="main">';

            echo '<div class="pf-container">';

                echo '<div class="pf-row">';

                    if ($setup_item_blogcatpage_sidebarpos == 3) {

                        echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';



                            get_template_part('loop');



                        echo '</div>';

                    }else{



                        if($setup_item_blogcatpage_sidebarpos == 1){

                            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">';

                                if (is_active_sidebar( 'pointfinder-blogcatpages-area' )) {



                                    get_sidebar('catblog' );

                                } else {

                                    get_sidebar();

                                }



                            echo '</div>';

                        }



                        echo '<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">'; 



                        get_template_part('loop');



                        echo '</div>';

                        if($setup_item_blogcatpage_sidebarpos == 2){

                            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">';

                                if (is_active_sidebar( 'pointfinder-blogcatpages-area' )) {

                                    get_sidebar('catblog' );

                                } else {

                                    get_sidebar();

                                }

                            echo '</div>';

                        }



                    }

                echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';

        echo '</section>';

        echo '<div class="pf-blogpage-spacing pfb-bottom"></div>';



    }else{

        $general_ct_page_layout = PFSAIssetControl('general_ct_page_layout','','1');



        if ($general_ct_page_layout == 1) {



            $pointfinderltypesas_vars = get_option('pointfinderltypesas_vars');

            $pf_cat_imagebg = (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_imagebg']))? $pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_imagebg']: 2;



            if ($pf_cat_imagebg == 1) {

                if(function_exists('PFGetDefaultCatPageHeader')){

                    PFGetDefaultCatPageHeader(

                        array(

                            'taxname' => $get_termname,

                            'taxnamebr' => $get_term_nameforlink,

                            'taxinfo'=>$term_name['description'],

                            'pf_cat_textcolor' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_textcolor']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_textcolor']:'',

                            'pf_cat_backcolor' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_backcolor']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_backcolor']:'',

                            'pf_cat_bgimg' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgimg']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgimg']:'',

                            'pf_cat_bgrepeat' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgrepeat']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgrepeat']:'',

                            'pf_cat_bgsize' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgsize']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgsize']:'',

                            'pf_cat_bgpos' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgpos']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_bgpos']:'',

                            'pf_cat_headerheight' => (isset($pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_headerheight']))?$pointfinderltypesas_vars[$term_name['term_id']]['pf_cat_headerheight']:'',

                        )

                    );

                }

            }else{

                if(function_exists('PFGetDefaultPageHeader')){

                    PFGetDefaultPageHeader(

                        array(

                            'taxname' => $get_termname,

                            'taxnamebr' => $get_term_nameforlink,

                            'taxinfo'=>$term_name['description']

                        )

                    );

                }

            }

        }



        /* Map Header */

        if ($general_ct_page_layout == 2) {



            /* Get Variables and apply */

            $setup42_searchpagemap_height = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_height','height','550');

            $setup42_mheight = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_mheight','height','350');

            $setup42_theight = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_theight','height','400');



            $setup42_searchpagemap_lat = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_lat','','');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_lng = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_lng','','');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_zoom = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_zoom','','12');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_mobile = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_mobile','','10');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_type = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_type','','ROADMAP');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_business = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_business','','0');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl','','1');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_style = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_style','',''));

            if (mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, 0, 1,'UTF-8') == '[' && mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, -1, 1,'UTF-8') == ']') {

                $setup42_searchpagemap_style = mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, 1, -1,'UTF-8');

            }

            $setup42_searchpagemap_style = base64_encode( strip_tags( $setup42_searchpagemap_style ));

            $setup42_searchpagemap_height = str_replace('px', '', $setup42_searchpagemap_height);

            $setup42_mheight = str_replace('px', '', $setup42_mheight);

            $setup42_theight = str_replace('px', '', $setup42_theight);

            $setup7_geolocation_status = 0;





            /* Build Map */



            $pfg_paged = 1;



            if ( is_front_page() ) {

                $pfg_paged = (esc_sql(get_query_var('page'))) ? esc_sql(get_query_var('page')) : 1;   

            } else {

                $pfg_paged = (esc_sql(get_query_var('paged'))) ? esc_sql(get_query_var('paged')) : 1; 

            }



            /*Get if sort/order/number values exist*/

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter']!=''){$pfg_orderby = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter']);}else{$pfg_orderby = $setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype;}

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']!=''){$pfg_order = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']);}else{$pfg_order = $setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype;}

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']!=''){$pfg_number = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']);}else{$pfg_number = "-1";}



            echo do_shortcode('[pf_directory_map setup5_mapsettings_height="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_height.'" setup42_mheight="'.$setup42_mheight.'" setup42_theight="'.$setup42_theight.'" setup5_mapsettings_zoom="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_zoom.'" setup5_mapsettings_zoom_mobile="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_mobile.'" setup8_pointsettings_ajax="0" setup5_mapsettings_autofit="1" setup5_mapsettings_autofitsearch="0" setup5_mapsettings_type="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_type.'" setup5_mapsettings_business="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_business.'" setup5_mapsettings_streetViewControl="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl.'" mapsearch_status="0" mapnot_status="0" setup5_mapsettings_lat="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_lat.'" setup5_mapsettings_lng="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_lng.'" setup5_mapsettings_style="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_style.'" setup7_geolocation_status="0" listingtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderltypes'].'" itemtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderitypes'].'" conditions="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderconditions'].'" features ="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderfeatures'].'" locationtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderlocations'].'" ppp="'.$pfg_number.'" paged="'.$pfg_paged.'" orderby="'.$pfg_orderby.'" order="'.$pfg_order.'"]');



        }





        $setup42_authorpagedetails_grid_layout_mode = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_grid_layout_mode','','1');

        $setup42_authorpagedetails_defaultppptype = $setup22_searchresults_defaultppptype;



        $setup22_searchresults_defaultlistingtype = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_dlcfc','','3');



        $setup42_authorpagedetails_grid_layout_mode = ($setup42_authorpagedetails_grid_layout_mode == 1) ? 'fitRows' : 'masonry' ;

        $setup22_searchresults_background2 = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_background2','','#ffffff');

        $setup22_searchresults_status_catfilters = PFSAIssetControl('setup22_searchresults_status_catfilters','','1');

        $stp22_infscrl_c = PFSAIssetControl('stp22_infscrl_c','',0);

        $stp22_infscrl_c2 = PFSAIssetControl('stp22_infscrl_c2','',0);



        if ($setup22_searchresults_status_catfilters == 1) {

            $filters_text = 'true';

        }else{

            $filters_text = 'false';

        }



        if($general_ct_page_layout == 1 || $general_ct_page_layout == 2){

            if ($general_ct_page_layout == 2) {

                $topmap_status = "1";

            }else{

                $topmap_status = "0";

            }

            $setup_item_catpage_sidebarpos = PFASSIssetControl('setup_item_catpage_sidebarpos','','2');

            echo '<section role="main">';

            if ($general_ct_page_layout == 2) {

                echo '<div class="pf-fullwidth pf-itempage-br-xm pf-itempage-br-xm-nh"><div class="pf-container"><div class="pf-row"><div class="col-lg-12">';

                            $br_output = pf_the_breadcrumb(array('taxname' => $get_term_nameforlink));

                echo '<div class="pf-breadcrumbs pf-breadcrumbs-special">'.$br_output.'</div></div></div></div></div>';

            }

                echo '<div class="pf-page-spacing"></div>';

                echo '<div class="pf-container"><div class="pf-row clearfix">';

                    if ($setup_item_catpage_sidebarpos == 3) {

                        echo '<div class="col-lg-12"><div class="pf-page-container">';

                            echo do_shortcode('[pf_itemgrid2 orderby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype.'" sortby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype.'" items="'.$setup42_authorpagedetails_defaultppptype.'" cols="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultlistingtype.'" grid_layout_mode="'.$setup42_authorpagedetails_grid_layout_mode.'" filters="'.$filters_text.'" itemboxbg="'.$setup22_searchresults_background2.'" infinite_scroll="'.$stp22_infscrl_c.'" infinite_scroll_lm="'.$stp22_infscrl_c2.'" termname="'.$get_termname.'" topmap="'.$topmap_status.'" '.$filter_text.']' );

                        echo '</div></div>';

                    }else{

                        if($setup_item_catpage_sidebarpos == 1){

                            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">';

                                get_sidebar('itemcats' ); 

                            echo '</div>';

                        }



                        echo '<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8"><div class="pf-page-container">'; 



                        echo do_shortcode('[pf_itemgrid2 orderby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype.'" sortby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype.'" items="'.$setup42_authorpagedetails_defaultppptype.'" cols="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultlistingtype.'" grid_layout_mode="'.$setup42_authorpagedetails_grid_layout_mode.'" filters="'.$filters_text.'" itemboxbg="'.$setup22_searchresults_background2.'" infinite_scroll="'.$stp22_infscrl_c.'" infinite_scroll_lm="'.$stp22_infscrl_c2.'" termname="'.$get_termname.'" topmap="'.$topmap_status.'" '.$filter_text.']' );



                        echo '</div></div>';

                        if($setup_item_catpage_sidebarpos == 2){

                            echo '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">';

                                get_sidebar('itemcats' );

                            echo '</div>';

                        }

                    }



                echo '</div></div>';

                echo '<div class="pf-page-spacing"></div>';

            echo '</section>';

        }elseif ($general_ct_page_layout == 3) {





            /* Get Variables and apply */





            $setup42_searchpagemap_lat = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_lat','','');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_lng = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_lng','','');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_zoom = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_zoom','','12');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_mobile = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_mobile','','10');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_type = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_type','','ROADMAP');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_business = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_business','','0');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl = PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl','','1');

            $setup42_searchpagemap_style = preg_replace('/\s+/', '',PFSAIssetControl('setup42_searchpagemap_style','',''));

            if (mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, 0, 1,'UTF-8') == '[' && mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, -1, 1,'UTF-8') == ']') {

                $setup42_searchpagemap_style = mb_substr($setup42_searchpagemap_style, 1, -1,'UTF-8');

            }

            $setup42_searchpagemap_style = base64_encode( strip_tags( $setup42_searchpagemap_style ));

            $setup7_geolocation_status = 0;





            /* Build Map */



            /*Get if sort/order/number values exist*/

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter']!=''){$pfg_orderby = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter']);}else{$pfg_orderby = $setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype;}

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']!=''){$pfg_order = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter-order']);}else{$pfg_order = $setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype;}

            if(isset($_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']) && $_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']!=''){$pfg_number = esc_attr($_GET['pfsearch-filter-number']);}else{$pfg_number = "-1";}



            echo do_shortcode('[pf_directory_half_map orderby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsortbytype.'" sortby="'.$setup22_searchresults_defaultsorttype.'" setup5_mapsettings_zoom="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_zoom.'" setup5_mapsettings_zoom_mobile="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_mobile.'" setup5_mapsettings_autofit="1" setup5_mapsettings_autofitsearch="1" setup5_mapsettings_type="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_type.'" setup5_mapsettings_business="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_business.'" setup5_mapsettings_streetViewControl="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_streetViewControl.'" mapsearch_status="1" mapnot_status="1" setup5_mapsettings_lat="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_lat.'" setup5_mapsettings_lng="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_lng.'" setup5_mapsettings_style="'.$setup42_searchpagemap_style.'" setup7_geolocation_status="0" listingtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderltypes'].'" itemtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderitypes'].'" conditions="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderconditions'].'" features ="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderfeatures'].'" locationtype="'.$pf_mapheader_arr['pointfinderlocations'].'"  termname="'.$get_termname.'" csauto="'.$term_name['term_id'].'"]');



        }



    }





get_footer();

?>
```

On my research i have found that something like this should work:

```
<?php
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">continue reading</a>.';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
?>
```

But i'm not sure where to put this to make it work.

Thank you in advance for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in **functions.php** file (or in your custom functions file) inside theme directory.